# WebMvcConfig in a rest application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

we use spring boot 3, we have only rest api

i saw a lot of tutorial who show to use

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final long MAX_AGE_SECS = 3600;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("*")
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowedMethods("HEAD", "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE")
                    .maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);

    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        MediaType[] mediaTypes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_HTML, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM};
        configurer.defaultContentType(mediaTypes);
    }
}
```

is there any reason to use that in a rest application?

Comment: Not with `@EnableWebMvc` as that will disable large parts of the autoconfiguation for the web of Spring Boot. The rest still can make sense.